# Chunked upload validation: "The file could not be uploaded."

Tags: symfony, validation, debugging, file-upload, symfony4

I am currently trying to let Symfonys Validator Component handle the validation of uploaded files, which works perfectly fine for normal files. However, if files are above a certain size they are uploaded as chunks, which are then merged and then validated. Both ways to upload are validated by the same function, which basically just looks like this:

```
public function validateFile(UploadedFile $uploadedFile): ConstraintViolationList {

    return $this->validator->validate(
        $uploadedFile,
        [
            new FileConstraints([
                'maxSize' => '1000M',
            ]),
        ]
    );
}
```

But somehow, the merged uploads trigger a violation, which, unfortunately, is quite uninformative to me:

```
Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation {#658 ▼
  -message: "The file could not be uploaded."
  -messageTemplate: "The file could not be uploaded."
  -parameters: []
  -plural: null
  -root: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#647 ▶}
  -propertyPath: ""
  -invalidValue: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#647 ▶}
  -constraint: Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File {#649 ▶}
  -code: "0"
  -cause: null
}
```

The logs are clean, no errors, only INFO regarding matched routes and deprecated stuff aswell as DEBUG regarding authentificastion tokens and such.

If I dump'n'die the UploadedObjects the only difference is that the chunked & merged one has `executable: true` and that its not stored in tmp.

Can someone here explain to me what causes this violation and what has to be done to prevent it or point me to some documentation regarding that?

EDIT: The upload of chunks and the merging seems to work perfectly fine - uploaded images can be viewed, text docs/pdfs can be read etc. Also used all the other code for quite a while now with different validation, just wanted to make everything a bit more pro and sorted by using the existing Validator infrastructure. To provide additional info regarding the uploaded objects, here the dd output, starting with regular file upload:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#20 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "foo.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpEu7Xmw"
  basename: "phpEu7Xmw"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpEu7Xmw"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpEu7Xmw"
  aTime: 2021-05-27 10:47:56
  mTime: 2021-05-27 10:47:54
  cTime: 2021-05-27 10:47:54
  inode: 1048589
  size: 539474
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

For chunked upload:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#647 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "foo.jpg"
  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"
  -error: 0
  path: "/home/vagrant/MyProject/var/uploads"
  filename: "foo.jpg"
  basename: "foo.jpg"
  pathname: "/home/vagrant/MyProject/var/uploads/foo.jpg"
  extension: "jpg"
  realPath: "/home/vagrant/MyProject/var/uploads/foo.jpg"
  aTime: 2021-05-27 10:43:58
  mTime: 2021-05-27 10:43:58
  cTime: 2021-05-27 10:43:58
  inode: 8154
  size: 539474
  perms: 0100777
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: true
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

Comment: This can have different causes. I would recommend you following thinks:
1. Provide any logs if you have any.
2. Step into this classes while debugging and see what is happening inside there.
3. Try play around with maxSize maybe this is causing the exception.

Comment: @DariusMann Thanks for trying to help! No errors or similar in the logs, only INFO that routes for chunk uplaod and merge were matched and that some stuff is deprecated aswell es DEBUG output regarding auth. I already played around with maxSize . doesnt help, but if maxSize is way to low it still fails with "The file could not be uploaded." and not the max size related message so I guess it that shows that the check triggering the violation comes before the maxSize check. Regarding 2. - which class do you mean? The constraint class?

Comment: Are you certain that all chunks are correctly uploaded and reassembled? Have you checked the resulting file manually? Seems to me that the resulting file has been renamed somehow, but some more details are needed.

Comment: @msg Again, thanks for helping! I edited my post to provide more details (yes, files were manually tested)

Comment: @msg Omg you nailed it. Tested it by removing the `is_uploaded` check and it works fine. So I have to merge the chunks in /tmp and move the file afterwards. Thanks a lot, this, would be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `File` constraint receives an `UploadedFile` instance, it triggers a call to [`isValid`](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/ddc698d2a6a543b07ee42b445f490b9e90448ca2/Constraints/FileValidator.php#L54), which in turn calls [`is_uploaded_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php):

> Returns true if the file named by filename was uploaded via HTTP POST.
> This is useful to help ensure that a malicious user hasn't tried to
> trick the script into working on files upon which it should not be
> working

After reassembling the chunks into a new file this check no longer passes and the constraint fails.

You could use your last file fragment to reassemble the original file or you could return a [`File`](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/6058b19318aa27773cfb3014e9b11be54ac30aa2/File/File.php) from your function. `File` is not subject to that check, and the constraint will accept it along with `UploadedFile`.

Comment: Hi, thank you @msg. I'm adding a note here: UploadedFile object can be instantiated with the param `test` set to `true`. (according to relative answer by @Mark Brass)
e.g. `new UploadedFile('/path/to/file', 'filename', test: true);

Answer (score 1):

When creating your UploadedFile object programatically use the 'test mode'. I use this with the VichUploaderBundle and the use of test mode is documented [here](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/docs/known_issues.md).

Answer (score 0):

```
new Count([
  'min' => 1,
  'minMessage' => 'Please select a file to upload'
]),
```

I think the `NotBlank` constraint is the problem here, I don't think it should be used on `UploadedFile`.

Try using only the `File` and `Count` constraints (to make sure there is a minimum of 1 file attached).

Comment: Thanks for th tip :) Unfortunately `NotBlank` is not the issue, due to try and error I already know its the FileConstraint causing the problem. I will edit to make that clear!

Comment: Yeah my bad just checked the constraint violation belonged to File. Can you show the full constraint error on this line?
` -constraint: Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File {#649 ▶}`